# Term for the link a seller sends to a buyer to make payment

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Oftentimes when buying stuff online, the buyer receives a URL (like a PayPal link) from the seller, which the buyer then clicks to make a payment.

Is there a concise name for such a link?

- "URL that seller sent to buyer for making the payment" is too long
- "Payment link" could make people think that the seller sends a payment to them
- "Link for user to deposit payment" is a bit better but still long

Comment: "Make payment" ? Short and simple, I guess!

Comment: also very good term

Comment: How about "Pay/View My Bill" ? That's what my son's university calls their link when they "invite" me to pay his tuition.

Answer (score 1):

"Payment link" is perfectly fine, concise, understandable, and if you google around for it, that's a term people actually use.

Under no circumstances could "payment link" possibly make anyone think that the *seller* wants to pay the *buyer*, because sellers just do not pay buyers.

Answer (score 1):

[Bill link](https://www.google.com/search?q=bill%20link&oq=bill%20link&aqs=chrome..69i57.2889j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22billlink%22%20payment). In the paper world, we might call this a *bill*:

> noun
>
> 1 A printed or written statement of the money owed for goods or
>   services:
>   ODO

In the same way that a paper bill would have a slip to facilitate returning payment, this cyber-bill would have a link to facilitate payment.

Answer (score 0):

I first offered a comment to see if that's what the OP was looking for.

"Make Payment" indeed looks good in all aspects (to the OP too).

Some more suggestions include:

"Enter payment details"
"Enter billing info"
"Move to bill desk"

Comment: so i say "Make-Payment URL"

Comment: yeah looks good